# Null Pointer Exception for Default Shared Preference Manager

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Sometimes when I call edit on the Default Shared Preferences, I get a NullPointerException. Does anybody know why this is? Below is my code and error.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesFinish = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
SharedPreferences.Editor speF = sharedPreferencesFinish.edit();


java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
      'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: `getActivity()` is the context you are passing. Chances are that context is somehow wrong, but there is no way to tell from from this snippet.